# How do I configure annotations to map servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, annotations

I'm trying to use annotations in my project on AppEngine, but they don't work at all. I've tried almost everything to configure them, but they still don't work.

I'm using servlet 3.1.0, with runtime java8.

When I tried to look for the servlet mapped with the annotation into the console I can read:

```
 [java] WARNING: No file found for: /testServlet
     [java] giu 13, 2019 11:50:45 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
```

Here are my files:

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProgettoEsame</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>ProgettoEsame</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
      <version>0.7</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.74</version>
      </plugin>    
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Tried with version="3.0" and metadata-complete="false", but still nothing
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>ProgettoEsame</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>registra</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>registra</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>registra</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registra</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"
xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xsi:schemaLocation='http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/downloads/download/schema/appengine-web.xsd appengine-web.xsd'>
    <application>ProgettoEsame</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Servlet: registra.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Gabriel
 */

@WebServlet(name = "registra", urlPatterns = "/testServlet")
public class registra extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet registra</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet registra at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();
            out.println("Servlet version = " + sc.getMajorVersion() + "." + sc.getMinorVersion());
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify urlPatterns into {}

@WebServlet(name = "registra", urlPatterns = "{ /testServlet } ")

Here you need to edit into web.xml

```
  <servlet-name>registra</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/testServlet</url-pattern>
```

Can you change into web.xml

Because is you are using multiple attributes then have to specify url patterns into curly braces.

Source :  https://javatutorial.net/servlet-annotation-example

Comment: Not working, still 404 Error page not found: 

     [java] giu 13, 2019 12:19:55 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
     [java] WARNING: No file found for: /testServlet

Comment: <servlet-name>registra</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testServlet</url-pattern>

Can you change into web.xml

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I'm trying to use annotations. I suppose that if I can't use them like this I won't be able to use them also for datastore (I'd like to use objectify)